# Winform Segoe UI font blurry

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I somehow get a difference in UI smoothness while developing Winform project.

I use Segoe UI font, with 9.25px size.

Here is the comparison between the Visual Studio (Dev) and debugged one (Prod) :

**Dev**

[image: Dev]

**Prod**

[image: Prod]

The difference is quite visible, on the font, button, window bar.

These are the settings I tried :

1. On Visual Studio, set AutoScaleMode = Dpi
2. On Windows, set Appearance to Best Appearance mode

How to fix this? And what causes this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms high DPI blurry fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts?rq=1) right after.

I seems like windows can't upscale the dpi so we need to tell that the application is able to handle the DPI.